# Programmatically add multiple xslt list view web parts pointing to specific subfolder within a sharepoint library

Tags: javascript, xslt, xslt-list-view-web-part, client-side-rendering

I have a list of items linked to a library in sharepoint. I have created a custom rendering logic for list items and would like to add to each item a xsltlistviewwebpart pointing to a specific subfolder within the library if possible. So my list look like this
[image: Current status]

and I would like to achieve something like this

[image: Desired goal]

I am using Sharepoint designer and just client side code (javascript, html)

Answer (score 0):

Since you can use client-side coding, I would create you tables yourself and populate them how you want instead of relying on using the SharePoint web parts.  It is going to be less of a headache that way, and you will be able to cater your results more to your requirements.

Create you a new SharePoint Web Part page, and create your tables there.  This is going to be your best bet IMO.  Good luck!